# From where REST API is downloaded

Tags: marklogic

I want to install the REST API on my system.

Where can I install the REST API.

I have installed the Marklogic server on my system so far.

Answer (score 6):

- If you are using MarkLogic 8, then there is nothing to install - its at port 8000.
- If You are using MarkLogic 6 or 7, then you create it via admin (and you
  are actually confiiguring an app server, not really installing 
  anything)
- If you are using MarkLogic 5, then upgrade.. If not, look at Corona.. No, really - upgrade..

But in **all** cases, the starting point is exactly where PeteA suggests.....

Answer (score 4):

Have you read the documentation [here](https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/rest/setup#create-a-rest-api-instance)?

It has instructions on how to create a REST API instance, configure the DB and create the rest users.

Comment: Thanks every one.......one more doubt......how to install curl.exe in local machine